# multiple domains and one administration panel

Tags: php, web, administration

I have 3 domains and I want to write one administration panel.
90% of code is common for all websites.

Is it good idea to use one *index.php* and `$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]` to find out which site to show?
Or maybe use four folders in root (one for each website) and keep common files out  of these folders.

Eg.

```
ROOT
        WWW1
        /index.php

    WWW2
        /index.php

    WWW3
        /index.php

    ADMIN
        /index.php

    /config.cfg

    /.htaccess

    IMG

    MEDIA
        IMG
        DOCS
        MUSIC
        VIDEO

    SRC
    JS
    CSS
```

Or maybe there is other solution.

Comment: If the differences are small enough to be contained in a single root *ini* (or *config*) type file you could have just one codebase with different ini files per site. Define the path to the ini file, as an environment variable, in the `<VirtualHost ... >` directive, in your Apache `httpd-vhosts.conf` file. Then at the start of your script you can require it with `require_once $_SERVER['ini_path'];` - each site will then pull in its own ini file. This assumes you're using a dedicated Apache server with all the relevant access of course.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not server owner so I can't edit httpd-vhosts.conf file.

Answer (score 1):

This is a decision that there is no "right answer" for - it's a decision that needs to be made on a per-site basis. As you've already identified, if most of the code is common across all the sites, sharing them does make a lot of sense.

You might also want to think about what kind of admin tasks you're expecting: are these sites going to have the same admin or is there a different set for each site? Will these administrators have similar needs / abilities? If they are, again a shared admin makes a lot of sense.

In terms of one index vs an index for each site: how much config / setup do your sites require? If all sites run almost the same way, one index page might make sense, and then the 10% of code that's different can be handled on an adhoc basis. Again, if the bootstrap / setup needs to be very different for each site, a separate index for each site makes sense, so they can set up their own environments before calling the 90% similar code.

So, in conclusion, I'm not going to say "yes" or "no" to anything because I don't know enough about your setup to give a solid answer. However, I have worked on sites that follow schemes like this successfully, and you seem to be following a sensible logic, so this solution certainly doesn't have any glaring issues.

Hope this helps :) x

Comment: Thanks for your tips. This is a one project and is divided on three subprojects. So most of images, medias and code will be common. There will be one database for all. Admin will manage content of these sites from one place (some kind of CMS joomla). But I'm afraid of complications. If I use separate folders for each site index.php will be "higher" than the rest of code.

Comment: This setup shouldn't yield any glaring complications with the sites you've described. Does having the main index.php file in a "higher" folder cause an issue? x

Comment: When I will use separate index.php for each site the domain eg. mydomain1.com will point /WWW1 folder, mydomain2.com /WWW2 folder and so on. But rest of files will be placed in /IMG, /SRC etc. folders.